# Atom for angularJs2 beta + spring boot

Tags: spring, typescript, angular

I work with Atom 1.4.0 with atom-typescript package to write the angularjs2 modules in typescript. At the backend side I have a spring-boot application for the rest api's.

When I change the `.ts` files atom seems to compile the file and generate the `.js`. But when I use chrome to see the changes I don't see any change (I switch on Developer console and I saw on the `.ts` and `.js` file that the changes were not loaded.

I tryied to restart Atom, the backend server, to clear the cache on chrome, explorer, firefox, to make a build evry time after saving a `.ts` file but the behaviour don't change. I don't know were I have the mistake.

A colegue has the same setup, same project (I copied from him) same version of atom, but by him the changes are visibible istantiantly.

> Any Idea?

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
},
"compileOnSave": true,
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
 "name": "resend",
 "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
  "tsc": "tsc",
  "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "dependencies": {
   "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
   "systemjs": "0.19.6",
   "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
   "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
   "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
   "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
   "zone.js": "0.5.10",
   "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
   "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
   "typescript": "^1.7.3"
 }
}
```

Comment: Click F12 in Chrome, go to the "Network" tab and select the "Disable cache" checkbox and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was in the eclipse workspace. The folder were my frontend files are, were not updated, and eclipse blocked the refresh. After I found the solution with manual refresh on the folder (in Eclipse under the Project manager), I found also the solution to tell eclipse to listen to this folder:

Under `Windows`->`Preferences`->`General`->`Workspace`

I enabled the two flags:

- Refresh using native hooks or polling
- Refresh on access